# How to convert Nonetype to int?

Tags: python

```
def kareler(x:int,y:int):
    toplam=0

    for i in range(x,y):
        toplam+=i**2
    return toplam


def tkareler(x:int,y:int):
    toplam1=0
    for i in range(x,y):
        toplam1+=i

    return toplam1**2


sayi1=print(kareler(1,11))
sayi2=print(tkareler(1,11))

print("Gerekli sayi",sayi2-sayi1) # TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

if type(sayi1)==None:
    sayi1=int(sayi1)

    print(sayi1)  #  this even not give any result to me
```

Hello i get 2 result  385 and 3025 but when i want subtract both result i get error how can i convert none type to integer

Comment: The print() function always returns None. Just do sayi1 = kareler(1,11) without the print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get an int value out of a `None`.  Instead, use the int value you got from your function.  Change this:

```
sayi1=print(kareler(1,11))
sayi2=print(tkareler(1,11))
```

to this:

```
sayi1 = kareler(1,11)
sayi2 = tkareler(1,11)
print(f"{sayi1}/n{sayi2}")
```

The `print` function returns `None`, not the thing you told it to print!

Comment: oh okay it worked i understan thank u very much it means when i want to get result of function as integer, i shouldn`t  write `print` i should just write function name and assign to variable

Comment: Yes; in general the exact things you type are important.  :)  Adding extra things to a line of code will usually change the way it works.